# Why is method overload resolution determined at compile time?

Tags: java, virtual-functions, dynamic-dispatch

I am trying to understand why we have polymorphism / dynamic binding with overridden methods, but not overloaded methods. I understand that there’s indirection that allows us to index into a vtable to allow us to do this in a language like C++ or Java. I’m curious why the same isn’t the case for resolving overloaded methods — my intuition leads me to believe we could have a level of indirection that allows us to determine at runtime which overloaded method to invoke based on the runtime type.

I’m wondering if this design decision was made for performance reasons or if there’s extra complexity I’m neglecting to consider.

Comment: Because designing it this way is in line with the design principles of Java, namely that Java's type system is static. For a more elaborate answer, you'd have to ask the language designers.

Comment: @Sweeper I suppose I'm maybe fundamentally confused though on why then we can still have runtime polymorphism and it be considered static typing, but it wouldn't be if we did dynamic resolution of overloaded methods. Maybe that would be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Would overload resolution based on runtime types be useful? I think it’d just leave me confused about how my code is going to behave. I understand your question, though.

Comment: There are programming languages where normal method arguments affects the method resolution at runtime, in the same way as the receiver argument (the "this" argument). This mechanism is usually called [*multiple dispatch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch). Many dynamic languages have this feature, for example Clojure and Groovy. Proponents of those languages often insist that the feature is a very useful design tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not read the minds of the language designers, so cannot really tell you. I am thinking of it in this way:

- Overridden methods are different implementations of the same method at different levels in the superclass/subclass hierarchy. The subclass generally uses the same method signature (it’s allowed to return a more specific type and to declare fewer exceptions to be thrown, but it cannot completely redefine the method header, or it will no longer be an override).
- Overloaded methods are really just different methods that happen to have the same name. Then the parameter types are used for distinguishing. Just like the compiler always decides on compile time which method to call, this is also the case with overloaded methods.

As an observation (possibly a minor one), with runtime resolution of overloaded methods we could no longer statically type check the return value. Imagine we have

```
public boolean foo(Number n);
public String foo(Integer i);
```

Now I would find it perfectly natural to call the former `foo()` like this:

```
    boolean result = foo(myNumber);
```

Now if `myNumber` happened to be an `Integer`, the latter `foo()` would be called instead. It would return a `String` and I would have a type conversion error happening on runtime. I would not be amazed.

> … why then we can still have runtime polymorphism and it be considered
> static typing, but it wouldn't be if we did dynamic resolution of
> overloaded methods.

Java has both: a static type and a runtime type. When I store an `Integer` into a variable declared to be a `Number`, then `Number` is the static type and `Integer` is the runtime type (BTW a type is not the same as a class). And you are correct, when I do `myObject.foo(arg)`, then the runtime type of `myObject` decides which implementation of `foo()` gets called. And conceivably the runtime type of `arg` could have been involved in the decision too. It would get more complicated, and I am unsure about the gain.

Comment: Thank you! What you mention about static type checking of the return value makes a lot of sense. I suppose in terms of gain, one common piece people mention when speaking of the visitor pattern is that it's a workaround to support double dispatch, so I think my question was wondering then why it's not built directly into the language at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Overloaded methods are methods that have the same name but take different parameters. You can simply see the types and order of the parameters it takes (also the type of value it returns) as part of the name.

In C++ this is actually somewhat more "exposed" - this language internally tweaks the names to match the parameters, `void h(int, char)` becomes something like `h__Fic` and `void h(int)` like `h__Fi`. These mangled names can be occasionally seen in places like error messages about them not being resolved. In Java, this is less exposed but internally comparable. This is also called the "signature".

Then you question simplifies to "if the methods have different names, why are they resolved at the compilation time and not a the run time?". The resolution between the two methods with different signatures cannot change over time, so there is simply no reason and no benefit to delay it.

Comment: I appreciate the response — maybe my question could be clearer. This question is more about language design and the simplified question isn't quite what I was getting at. Name mangling, while important, doesn't exactly answer why overloaded method resolution couldn't use a layer of indirection for resolution at runtime. I'm asking more a question of why we need something like the visitor pattern in the first place, or alternatively why we can't have multiple dispatch supported directly in the language.

Comment: Everything can be done at runtime and interpreted languages do exactly this.